# ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest suppresses exceptions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, integration-testing, actiondispatch

When debugging failing integration tests, I keep running into the same problem where the exceptions raised in my code are suppressed and not shown in the testing output.

For example, for the following controller and test:

```rb
class RegistrationController::ApplicationController
  def create
    # some code that raises an exception
  end
end
```

```rb
class RegistrationFlowTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

  test 'user registers successfully' do
    post sign_up_path, params: { username: 'arnold', password: '123' }
    assert_response :success  
  end

end
```

The output is something like

```rb
Minitest::Assertion: Expected response to be a <2XX: success>, but was a <500: Internal Server Error>
```

Is there a way to see the exact raised exception? Instead of just the difference of HTTP response code?

Thanks!

Simon

Comment: Might be only that you mised a colon on your params, so instead of ```post sign_up_path, params { username: 'arnold', password: '123' }```,  try ```post sign_up_path, params: { username: 'arnold', password: '123' }```, additionally check sign_in_path.

Comment: Nope, just a typo when writing the question, but good catch :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My recommended approach to this issue would be to actually parse the response provided by Rails (at least by default in `test` and `development` environments) which includes the stacktrace for the error and handle that in the case that your test fails. This has the advantage that it won't output the stacktrace when errors are raised that don't result in failing tests (e.g. scenarios where you are intentionally testing how failures are handled).

This little module that I've crafted will allow you to call `assert_response_with_errors` to assert the response to a call but output the exception message and stack trace in a readable format when the response is not what you expected.

```
module ActionDispatch
  module Assertions
    module CustomResponseAssertions
      # Use this method when you want to assert a response body but also print the exception
      # and full stack trace to the test console.
      # Useful when you are getting errors in integration tests but don't know what they are.
      #
      # Example:
      # user_session.post create_gene_path, params: {...}
      # user_session.assert_response_with_errors :created
      def assert_response_with_errors(type, message = nil)
        assert_response(type, message)
      rescue Minitest::Assertion => e
        message = e.message
        message += "\nException message: #{@response.parsed_body[:exception]}"
        stack_trace = @response.parsed_body[:traces][:'Application Trace'].map { |line| line[:trace] }.join "\n"
        message += "\nException stack trace start"
        message += "\n#{stack_trace}"
        message += "\nException stack trace end"
        raise Minitest::Assertion, message
      end
    end
  end
end
```

To use this, you need to include it into ActionDispatch::Assertions before Rails has loaded its stack in your `test_helper.rb`. So just prepend the include into your `test_helper.rb`, like this:

```
ActionDispatch::Assertions.include ActionDispatch::Assertions::CustomResponseAssertions
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
require 'rails/test_help'
...
```

Answer (score 0):

This will happen because Rails controllers by default handle exceptions and raise the 500 status, making the exceptions invisible to the test suite (which is very helpful if errors are raised in unit tests of a model). Options for disabling this in your test suite, or alternative workarounds, are discussed [here](https://www.dan-manges.com/blog/debugging-rails-integration-tests).

The key lines of code from that link, which should be added to `test/integration/integration_test_helper.rb`:

```
ActionController::Base.class_eval do
  def perform_action
    perform_action_without_rescue
  end
end

Dispatcher.class_eval do
  def self.failsafe_response(output, status, exception = nil)
    raise exception
  end
end
```

EDIT: I've noticed that that link is quite old now. I'm really familiar with Rack, so whilst the first block looks ok to me, I'm not sure if the second will still be current. You might need to have a look at [the relevant current Rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/rails_on_rack.html#action-dispatcher-middleware-stack%20Rails%20on%20Rack) if it needs bringing up to date.

Comment: I'm getting `Uncaught exception: uninitialized constant Dispatcher
`. That article is very old indeed. Couldn't find anything useful in the rails guide either. There's a middleware called `ActionDispatch::ShowExceptions` but it's already included in my project. I also have the following configuration for the test environment:  `config.action_dispatch.show_exceptions = true`

Comment: Have you tried just the first block about the controller?

Comment: I did now, no difference :(

Comment: @rwold My biggest problem with this issue is that it won't work if the scenario in which you are testing is one where you expect an error HTTP status (e.g. testing uploading a file with an invalid format) but not the error HTTP status produced (e.g. authentication failed). If you take a look at my answer, it will allow you to test error statuses and still log the error stacktrace when the status is not the one you expected.